# Refactor concatenation in ES6 style

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to refactor this code in a nicer way without exceeding an 80 char line limit.

```
 document.getElementById('latest-date').innerHTML =
    (
      days[date.getDay() -1] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ' ' +
      months[date.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.getFullYear() + ' - ' +
      date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes()
    );
```

I wanted to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but I think when I go to newline in order to follow char limit it will automatically add `\n`?

An example of the output of the current code is :

```
Thur 24 Aug, 2017 - 18:30
```

Comment: You can use momentJS to perform display of any sort of date stuff using momentJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('latest-date').innerHTML = (`
  ${days[date.getDay() -1]} ${date.getDate()}
  ${months[date.getMonth()]}, ${date.getFullYear()} - 
  ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}    
`);
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: I asked for ES6 refactor because I really don't want to add JQuery to the project. Nice solution and it does look nice, but doesn't answer my question directly. 

I marked as duplicate question anyway as suggested by community.

Comment: @Dean this doesn't use jQuery. It is using template literals. The `$` is deceiving, but that has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Exactly what @TinyGiant said. When you're inside the backticks (` `) you use ${ } to input a javascript variable and anything outside of it is rendered HTML. That's what you can remove all of you + ' ' + etc.

Comment: -1:                                                                    This does exactly what is not wanted, it adds linebreaks to the result string.

Comment: @Dave Wow! My mistake. This actually works perfectly and is not using JQuery like I thought. However, I'm still confused why this works.

Comment: @Dave How come it doesn't work here?: https://jsbin.com/jupoqemigo/edit?js,console

Comment: Glad it worked! I pushed it out without testing it (don't tell). 

I'll try and explain it simply: 

The reason template literals help is you don't need to constantly go inside and outside a string when you want to concatenate. The backticks give you the power to start a string but anytime you put ${javascript} or a ${variable} or a {date.getDate()} in there it automatically concatenates it for you. Anything outside of ${} will be considered part of that string.

Hope that helps @Deancoakley

Comment: @Dave Hmm, I found that if I `console.log()` it has the \n but if I `document.write()` it. My desired output in one line is achieved. This is strange to me.